# Hive equivalent of LISTAGG

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a query like this in oracle,But I want a hive equivalent SQL for this.Can some one guide me what is the hive equivalent of the below

'[' || LISTAGG(t3.measure_title, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t3.measure_title) || ']' all_measure_desc.How can this be rewritten in Hive.

My Query in Oracle is

```
SELECT 
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk,
    '[' || LISTAGG(t3.measure_title, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t3.measure_title) || ']' all_measure_desc
FROM qms_gic_lifecycle t1 
INNER JOIN dim_member t2 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN dim_quality_measure t3 
on t1.quality_measure_id = t3.quality_measure_id
GROUP BY  
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` or `collect_set` depending on how duplicate values should be handled. `collect_list` retains duplicate values while `collect_set` eliminates duplicates.

The output would be an *array* of values.

```
SELECT 
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk,
    COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title) as all_measure_desc
FROM qms_gic_lifecycle t1 
INNER JOIN dim_member t2 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN dim_quality_measure t3 
on t1.quality_measure_id = t3.quality_measure_id
GROUP BY  
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk;
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can use collect_list or collect_set depending on how duplicate values should be handled. collect_list retains duplicate values while collect_set eliminates duplicates.
>
> The output would be an array of values.

You can use concat_ws(string SEP, array) function to convert resulting array to string

```
concat_ws(',', COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title) ) as all_measure_desc
```

Comment: Please kindly give more details about your answer to help others understand it.